# Tracking lead source from Adwords

Tags: web2lead, google, adwords

currently we have Some web to lead forms that we built in our web site. As well as Adwords campaigns are also on going to increase Marketing. We would like to capture marketing ROI, So we want to capture Lead source according to the source of lead for e.g. google Adwords, google organic search or web referral. As per my study I saw that Salesforce Adwords app has been retired. Could you please advice me to Identify these lead sources separately.